# How do I clean phone numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column for Phone however, the data is a bit inconsistent.  Here are some examples that I would like to focus on.

```
df["Phone"]
0         732009852
1         738073222
2         755920306
3        0755353288
```

Row 3 has the necessary leading 0 for an Australian number. How do I update rows like 0,1 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or `pd.Series.str.rjust`:

```
print(df["Phone"].str.rjust(10, '0'))
```

Output:

```
0        0732009852
1        0738073222
2        0755920306
3        0755353288
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `pandas.Series.str.zfill`:

```
s = pd.Series(['732009852', '0755353288'])
s.str.zfill(10)
```

Output:

```
0    0732009852
1    0755353288
```